# How to know that local server is really down?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ssh, linux-networking

I have a local server in my company and I'm trying to SSH it and I get

ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.80 port 22: No route to host.

and when ping it I get

```
PING 192.168.1.80 (192.168.1.80) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.7 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

and I can't get to it now, because the the room is locked.

Answer (score 1):

There are various hints you can take:

- check ARP table for successful resolution of IP address
- check switch port link status
- check switch port MAC address association
- check whether LOM is reachable (e.g. HP iLO, Dell iDRAC)
- check LOM hardware status

Ultimately, these can tell you whether the destination is connected to the network and somewhat functional. They can't tell you whether the machine is disconnected or unpowered. For this, you'd need to check the power reading on a PDU or UPS (if available) or do a visual check.

Comment: Tried to use ARP, and it gives me that 
#arp -a
? (192.168.1.2) at e0:61:b2:02:b9:bf [ether] on wlan0
? (192.168.1.1) at 30:99:35:8c:84:93 [ether] on wlan0
? (192.168.1.80) at <incomplete> on wlan0

Comment: If you are using a smart UPS like APC and so on this might be another option to check whether the server is running and consuming power or not.

Comment: @NetRunner Good point - goes along with the PDU suggestion.

Comment: @ElwiMamdouh `ARP ... incomplete` indicates that the host is not responding to ARP requests (or the response isn't received).

Comment: @NetRunner I guess there isn't a PDU here.

Comment: @Zac67 so it might be down?

Comment: @ElwiMamdouh This is wireless? Yes, it might be down - or the NIC deactivated, antenna disconnected, blocked at the WAP, ... If you know the MAC address and the server supports this, you can try sending a WoWLAN to wake it up.

Comment: No it's LAN not a wirless

Comment: Great - WoL works much better than WoWLAN.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of "being down" can vary in many levels.

If the server normally replies to `ping`, then one can make a conclusion that now the server does not either send back reply packets or the packets do not reach the ping origin.

So, the server could have no power, it might not have network connectivity, the network between server and client might not work correctly.

Comment: I mean with " being down " is powered off. How can I check that it's not a network problem?